# The "GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata" task could not be instantiated

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Followed the steps to create a sample Azure function from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio.
The function runs fine locally (using F5), but when I try to publish it to Azure I get the following exception:

```
2>The "GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata" task could not be instantiated from "C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.1\build\..\tools\net46\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.dll". Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
2>The "GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
The file "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.dll" does exist on the specified location.
```

The project contains the following NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.16.0" />     
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.3" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
```

Visual Studio version: 16.8.5

What can be done to investigate this problem further?

Answer (score 0):

One or all of the below can solve your issue:

- Make sure that all the prerequisites are installed in your Visual Studio 2019:

  [image]
- Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution and rebuild. Now, deploy your solution.
- Create a function app on your Azure portal, and then select the function app in Visual Studio, instead of creating through Visual Studio, for deployment.
- Make sure, your `configuration` in Visual Studio is set to `Release`.